# Why doesn't Oracle's JDK (8, 7 and lower?) take LC_* environment variables into account?

Tags: java, localization, environment-variables

This sample output doesn't give what I expect with regards to locale settings... While this has been compiled and run with Java 8, the problem also shows on Java 7. Both JDKs from Oracle, fully patched Ubuntu 13.10.

```
fge@alustriel:/tmp$ locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_US
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
fge@alustriel:/tmp$ cat Main.java 
import java.nio.charset.Charset;

public final class Main
{
    public static void main(final String... args)
    {
        System.out.println(Charset.defaultCharset());
        System.out.println(System.getProperty("file.encoding", "UNKNOWN!"));
    }
}
fge@alustriel:/tmp$ javac Main.java
fge@alustriel:/tmp$ java Main
UTF-8
UTF-8
fge@alustriel:/tmp$ LC_ALL=fr_FR.ISO-8859-1 java Main
US-ASCII
ANSI_X3.4-1968
```

`fr_FR.ISO-8859-1` is installed on my system; why, then, is the default character set `US-ASCII`? Also, `file.encoding` is also set to ASCII, since [`ANSI_X3.4-1968` looks like it is an alias to ASCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#Aliases) Even though ISO-8859-1 is fully supported by my system...

Comment: I'd guess that it's not actually installed. This is the behaviour you get when java can't determine the locale. Does `locale -a` display fr_FR? You should check `user.language` and `user.country` properties to determine if it's actually picking up french, and not `en_US.ASCII`

Comment: @Petesh `locale -a` indeed doesn't show this locale, which is really strange... I must have botched the way I installed it...